# Python integration within Stata

Tags: python, stata, urllib

I am trying to run the python urllib module from the python interface in Stata, but it sends me the following message error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'

This happens when I run the script within the python interface in Stata. However, it works well when I run the script directly from spyder. Could you please give me any advice regarding this issue?

Comment: Are they the same version of Python? You can check using `import sys; print(sys.version)`.

Comment: Thanks, in this case they are the same version (3.8.8.)

Answer (score 0):

Agreeed with Nick ODell's comment: you should check your python path in Stata. and also you can change the path like this:

```
set python_exec "YOUR PATH FILE PATH\python.exe"
```